# C# number guessing game on Visual Studio. How to stop game from restarting and creating new random number with every click?

Tags: c#, webforms

I know this is simple stuff for you guys and I am sorry to take up your time but I have searched and tried everything on here in related posts.

Im trying to create simple guessing game in visual studio 2017. User tries to guess number between 1 and 10 via textbox and receives output in a label. I have it working (kind of) but it restarts the game and creates new random number with each click. Ive tried adding while loop but it just keeps going forever with no output. What do I need to add to my code to stop the game from restarting with every click and let the user continue to input guesses?

Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
public partial class NumberGame : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Random rand = new Random();
        int value = rand.Next(0, 10);
        int numGuess = 0;
        int guess = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuess.Text);


            if (guess > value)
            {
                numGuess++;
                lblResult.Text = "Guess is too high, try again. ";
                lblGuess.Text = "The number of guesses is " + numGuess;
            }
            else if (guess < value)
            {
                numGuess++;
                lblResult.Text = "Guess is too low, try again. ";
                lblGuess.Text = "The number of guesses is " + numGuess;
            }
            else if (guess == value)
            {
                numGuess++;
                lblResult.Text = "You win! Good job. ";
                lblGuess.Text = "The number of guesses is " + numGuess;

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: The code in `btnCalculate_Click` is called **every time the button is clicked**. You need to generate and store the number of guesses and the number somewhere else.

Comment: Make `rand`, `value` and `numGuess` class fields, so they persist between calls to `btnCalculate_Click`. `public partial class NumberGame : System.Web.UI.Page
{ Random rand = new Random();
        int value = rand.Next(0, 10);
        int numGuess = 0; protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) ... }`

Comment: Ohhh ok I see. I moved rand, value, and numGuess to the class field like you said but now I get this error on the line of code int value = rand.next(0,10);                  "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'NumberGame.rand'. Any idea what this means?

Comment: Did you make the fields Private or Public in scope? Eg `private Random rand .... `

Comment: @JeremyThompson  I honestly do not know. I haven't changed anything in the code above expect for moving 'rand', 'value', and 'numGuess' out of the click generator and up to public partial class like Oliver suggested in the previous comment. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the random number generation part to the form load event and assign it to a global variable.

public partial class NumberGame : System.Web.UI.Page
{

```
int value;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    value = rand.Next(0, 10);

}

protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int numGuess = 0;
    int guess = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuess.Text);

        do{
            if (guess > value)
            {
                numGuess++;
                lblResult.Text = "Guess is too high, try again. ";
                lblGuess.Text = "The number of guesses is " + numGuess;
            }
            else if (guess < value)
            {
                numGuess++;
                lblResult.Text = "Guess is too low, try again. ";
                lblGuess.Text = "The number of guesses is " + numGuess;
            }
            else if (guess == value)
            {
                numGuess++;
                lblResult.Text = "You win! Good job. ";
                lblGuess.Text = "The number of guesses is " + numGuess;

            }

        }while(numGuess < 3)

        Page_Load();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use the Static global variable for no of gussing instead taking as local variable because it will set every time to zero when button click control event will be called

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtGuess" placeHolder="Guess Number"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCalculate" OnClick="btnCalculate_Click" Text="Calculate" /><br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResult"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblGuess"></asp:Label><br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
static int numGuess=0;
Random rand = new Random();
protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value = rand.Next(0, 10);
    int guess = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuess.Text);
    if (guess > value)
    {
        numGuess++;
        lblResult.Text = "Guess is too high, try again. ";
    }
    else if (guess < value)
    {
        numGuess++;
        lblResult.Text = "Guess is too low, try again. ";
    }
    else if (guess == value)
    {
        numGuess++;
        lblResult.Text = "You win! Good job. ";
    }
    lblGuess.Text = "The number of guesses is " + numGuess;
}
```

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to add a bit of detail. What changed, and how does it fix OP's issue?

Comment: While this does answer the question, a code block by itself without any explanation won't provide any context to those who come across the same issue later. Like I said, you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this fixes the issue, not just a code dump. That said, I'll remove the downvote now.

Comment: I have added detail with code solution.So accept as answer.

Comment: @ArslanAli I made the changes you just suggested and it got rid of the error. But when I test it, it still starts over with every click and generates a new random number. I guess because 'value' is stored under the click generator. But if I move the variable to somewhere else like suggested in previous comments, the error just returns. Advice?

Comment: you are calling next(0,10) function out of the click function or out of any function while you know only data members properties can be initialized or declared as global variable in c# with some values.while if you want to use to store this value out of click function you can make your own function and use int value=rand.Next(0,10) there and use inside the load_Page() with if(isPostBack){CallThatFunction()} just like that one.

Comment: Is there anyway you could edit that into your answer so I can see what you are talking about? Not trying to annoy you I am just very new to this and have a horrible instructor. Thank you for fixing the number of guesses issue though. I do appreciate it.